# Generate opencv library 3.1 with opencv_contrib

Tags: android, opencv

You can create a library opencv 3.1 to [contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib) for Android? 
If so that the necessary steps and how can I make a simple test using matching SURF?

I'm using windows and android studio 2.2.

I saw several ways to try to generate .so but for earlier versions of opencv and using esperimental gradle, or cmake command line or even the visual cmake and / or even with Android.mk but do not know which easiest ...